# How To integrate jBoss Drools with Wso2 Micro Integrator to use Drools as Business Rules Mgmt System

Tags: jboss, wso2, drools, redhat-brms, wso2-esb

I have wso2 micro-integrator project implemented in hand, where the project has few hard-coded values & conditions in the business logic, so i want to make them as separate and implement those as rules using Drools(BRMS).

Then, how i could apply the Drools created rules on wso2 micro-integrated carbon applications.

Thanks for the help in advance,